# Inheritance in Love2d and Lua

Tags: inheritance, lua, love2d

I have a class with this set of values and functions:

```
require("class")

entity = class:new()

function entity:new()
    self.x = 100
    self.y = 100
    self.width = 32
    self.height = 32
    self.info = "entity"
    self.alive = true
    self.color = {r = 255, g = 0, b = 0}

    return self
end

function entity:load()
end

function entity:update()
    if self.alive then
    end
end

function entity:draw()
    if self.alive then
        love.graphics.setColor(self.color.r, self.color.g, self.color.b)
    end
end

function entity:destroy()
    self.alive = false
end
```

And I want to be able to use those same functions and values simply for other classes, like so:

```
require("entity")

local player = entity:new()

function player:load()
   self.color.r = 100
end

function player:update()
end
--etc etc
```

I come from a flash and As3 background, which if any of you know you may understand more or less what I'm trying to do.
So could anyone help me with this? All help is appreciated.

Comment: What class library are you using? Classes aren't built into Lua. Are you sure `entity:new()` creates a subclass and not an entity instance (if there's a difference)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this [class system](https://love2d.org/wiki/Simple_Educative_Class_System) to get the experience you are desiring to have. (Make sure to copy the code of the full version).

Your code would look like this:

```
require("class")

entity = class()

entity.x = 100
entity.y = 100
entity.width = 32
entity.height = 32
entity.info = "entity"
entity.alive = true
entity.color = {r = 255, g = 0, b = 0}


function entity:load()
end

function entity:update()
    if self.alive then
    end
end

function entity:draw()
    if self.alive then
        love.graphics.setColor(self.color.r, self.color.g, self.color.b)
    end
end

function entity:destroy()
    self.alive = false
end
```

And the second file:

```
require("entity")

local player = class()
player:addparent(entity)

function player:load()
   self.color.r = 100
end

function player:update()
end
```

Comment: Thanks for that. But one issue I seem to be facing is implementing that into my game. a small bit of initialization code :--                    player = player:load()
   enemy = enemy:load()
  game:add(player)
  game:add(enemy)              (game:add() merely adds the class to a table which uses a for loop for rendering) It returns an error saying "attempt to index global 'player' (a nil value) I have required the file.

Comment: @user3473758 I believe you have to do myPlayer = player:new() myPlayer:load() in order for your code to work. Also, if my answer helped you, would you mind accepting (by pressing the check-mark) it?  This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.